# What do I do when useEffect keeps fetching data after every single code change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

I checked my console and I noticed data was being fetched everytime my code change, I'm working with an API that has only limited accesss so this is kind of like a bum.

Fetching the data with useEffect, I included an empty dependency array so it only fetches the data once when the component is registered.

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
fetch('
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/tv?api_key=172f725b29bb24b6e294a988fc5&language=en-         US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres=16&without_genres=107%2C10759%2C99%2C80%2C35%2C10764%2C18%2C10751&with_watch_monetization_types=flatrate
')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data)),
),[]}
```

- I imported Home.jsx (which is the component fetching the data) into App.jsx

```
App.jsx
           <Router>
                <Navbar />
                <Routes>
                {/* right here is Home component being rendered*/}
                  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                  <Route
                    path="/artisteMusicOverview"
                    element={<ArtisteMusicOverview />}
                  />
                </Routes>
              </SearchContext.Provider>
            </Router>
```

How I do work my way around this bizarre complication please?

Comment: Please show the component that `useEffect` is in and the parent of that component

Comment: just use mock set of data when you are developing

Comment: *"I noticed data was being fetched everytime my code change"* It sounds like you're running some kind of live reloader (most bootstrapping scripts use one). When your code changes, it reloads the component, which necessarily means it re-mounts the component, thus triggering the effect. After all, what if the code you changed was in the effect?

Comment: Is that api key you posted for real?  If so you might even have less api requests..

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I made some edits, pls check it again.

Comment: @Keith It's the wrong key

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Isn't there something i can do if i don't want that to happen?

Comment: @Tomiwa - As people have mentioned, if you're using a limited resource, don't use it continually while developing. Grab a snapshot and develop against that snapshot. Or route the request through something that will cache previous results and keep them for X minutes during dev. Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Mock your API call

> I'm working with an API that has only limited access

Then don't fetch from that API while you are developing. Replace `fetch` by a mocking function returning mocked data (that you could copy from one real response of the API).

Once you are done developing, then you can replace it by a real fetch.

You could have some global switch/environment variable for switching between mock and real fetch, just make sure that your prod code will not call the mocked data.

### Why is useEffect triggered?

We don't know your entire development stack so this is just a guess, but you likely have some hot reload/fast refresh mechanism that remounts your component when you save a code change.